Where to get android sdk that read-write with felica card?
I'm new to NFC/Felica technologies. Previously, I worked with SLE4428 cards using an Android SDK provided by the card reader manufacturer.
Now, Felica cards seem to work directly with Android phones without external readers. I'm curious about how to obtain the necessary Android SDK for reading and writing to these cards. Do I need to contact Sony, the company behind Felica technology, to get the appropriate SDK?

You can retrieve a lot of informations about the FeliCa technology on the Sony website (manufacturer): https://www.sony.net/Products/felica/business/tech-support/. I for myself tested to read and write from/on a "FeliCa Lite-S RC-S966" (240 bytes) without any problems without any dedicated SDK.

" I for myself tested to read and write from/on a "FeliCa Lite-S RC-S966" (240 bytes) without any problems without any dedicated SDK."
But can we say the same for all types of felica cards though? For Felica Standard SD1 and SD2?

I can test with real NFC tags only and I don't own the types you named. But you should being able to read the data sheets and decide yourself. In the end all communication with an NFC tag is about sending and receiving a handfull of comands and responses. Ususally only the chapter "authentication" can be a little tricky. Good luck !

I hope the documentation provided by Felica is sufficient.
Are there any additional documents required? Given that Felica is proprietary, are there any subscription fees or licensing costs involved? @MichaelFehr

I'm sorry, for my coding I just searched for the "FeliCa Lite-S RC-S966" datasheet and got it without any problems or signing a "Non Disclosure Agreement" document. Usually all fees are covered by buying an NFC tag from that type. Usually the data sheet contains all informations to communicate with the tag. For some documents from manufacturer NXP I found that they provide a "feature and hints" document with additional informations, but I don't know for Sony/FeliCa. Just search for a data sheet and start.

It's built in to the generic Android SDK available as part of Android Studio
The Basics of Android NFC
But I would use the newer and better enableReaderMode API to interact with Tags
An example of how is at https://github.com/AndroidCrypto/AndroidBasicNfcReader
Specific Class for Felica Tags

Since felica is proprietary card, I wonder do I need to buy some kind of license?

Felica Tags conform to the NFC Type 3 standard, Android handles reading NDef data for you, so no need to buy any kind of license for that. If you want to know more about the Type 3 standard or other ISO standards then ISO will charge you money to read the standards. Some manufacturer do require NDA's or could charge fees to access documentation about how to use the more advanced features of their Tags, but in general any "License fee" is paid when you buy the Tag.

Okay, so there might be fees for accessing the protocol documentation. But since the cards come from Felica, should I contact them?

Depends on what you want to do and what datasheets they have freely available on the internet.

@Andrew: thanks for using the link to my repository (my Username on GH is AndroidCrypto). B.t.w. I'm planning to write a tutorial about FeliCa NFC tags in 3 to 4 months :-)

@MichaelFehr Yes I knew it was you and the code looks a lot like some of my StackOverflow answers, so I was happy to link it. Though I think it could do with some non Ndef I/O examples so that getting and correctly parsing transceive response can be shown and really the Repo should have a license file.

@Andrew: Thanks for reminding me to add a license - done for about 30 repos... Regarding: "non NDEF I/O examples": as my app is a "Beginner" application I wanted to use a code that is running on (nearly) every NFC tag. As there are a lot of tag types I'm just showing the Basics to do the first steps running in any case. But you are right, that might be an interesting "advanced" tutorial :-) Btw: same applies to my "Android HCE Beginner App" and tutorial (https://github.com/AndroidCrypto/Android_HCE_Beginner_App/) - there are so many things to append.
